# JavaScript Chessboard program

Tags: javascript

Here is my assignment:

> Write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid, using newline characters to separate lines. At each position of the grid there is either a space or a `#` character. The characters should form a chess board.

Passing this string to `console.log` should show something like this:

```
    # # # #
     # # # #
    # # # #
     # # # #
    # # # #
     # # # #
    # # # #
     # # # #
```

My attempt is below along with the comments to explain my logic. I get close but I can never get the pattern above. Whats wrong with my logic?

```js
//declar empty board
var board = "";

//use outter loop to control rows
for (var y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
  //use innerloop to generate the #'s horizonatlly
  for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++) {
    //if the row is even then put a space in front
    //of the board string and then generate the board
    // with the #'s
    if (y % 2 === 0) {
      board = " " + board;
      board += "#";
    }
    //else generate the board without a space in front
    //of the #'s
    else {
      board += "#";
    }
  }
  //generate a new line 
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a substitute for a debugger.  When you step through your code, where does the behavior differ from what you expect?

Comment: My output is Not correct and I dont understand why. I belive it has something to do with my if statement. Why did I get -1, this is not a valid question?

Comment: Not really, no.  Currently your question essentially is, "Here's all my code, debug it for me."  That's not really what Stack Overflow does.  Consider this an opportunity for *you* to learn how to use a debugger.  Do you have one?  If this is running in your browser then something like FireBug or Chrome developer tools would be very useful.  Set a breakpoint in your code and step through it, line by line, as it executes.  This is how you observe the runtime behavior to see where it differs from what you expect.  The code isn't a black box that generates output, you can examine it as it runs.

Comment: A few things I see quickly.  One is, why do both loops go from 1-4?  Shouldn't the outer one go from 1-8 (to make 8 rows)?  It also looks like you are confusing rows/columns.  Rows are horizontal, columns are vertical.

Comment: wanted to start smaller first... and change the values later.

Comment: Be consistent on where you add spaces. You add to the beginning with `board = " " + board` and to the end with `board += "#'`.

Comment: David, thank you for that, I was not aware of what you just explained above. Now I know.

Comment: Another issue is how you are checking whether or not to add a space before the `#`.  Here's a hint: you want to print 4 `#`s and 4 spaces, the only difference is which is first/last on each line.

Comment: Replacing `board = " " + board;` with `board += " ";` will point you to the right direction. When you write `board = " " + board;` you add a leading space to the entire string, and this is happening in a loop, hence the multiple whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to have some fun and write my own solution:

```js
var board = "";
var evenRow = "# # # # ";
var oddRow = " # # # #";

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

  if (i % 2 == 0) board += evenRow + '\n';
  else board += oddRow + '\n';
}

console.log(board);
```

Note: A chess board's proper orientation is white square lower right, which is a 90deg rotation from the answer's suggested output.

Comment: I like this solution!  Much better than mine: http://jsbin.com/woyevosi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Even I got overly fancy with the string reversal. Sometimes you just got to KISS.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```js
// declare size and an empty "board" string
var size = 8;
var board = "";

// Outerloop for rows
for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
  // inner loop for columns
  for (let j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) { // check if col is even
      board += " ";
    } else { // if col is odd
      board += "#";
    }
  }
  board += "\n"; // jump to next row
}
console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this implementation where i created the required lines of strings using loops according to the required grid size and finally conacte them with new line using another loop to output final result.

```js
//I Came Up With This

const gridSize = 8 ;  //your grid size

var str1 = "" ;  //first line of string  eg. # # # #
var str2 = "" ;  //second line of string eg.# # # #
var str = "" ;   //final string

//making str1 and str2 according to gridSize
for(var i = 0 ; i < gridSize ; i++){
    if(i%2==0){
        str1 += " " ;
        str2 += "#" ;
    }

    else{
        str1 += "#" ;
        str2 += " " ;
    }
}

//concatenating str1 and str2 with new line to final output str.
for(var i = 0 ; i < gridSize ; i++){
    if(i%2==0){
        str += str1+"\n" ;
    }

    else{
        str += str2+"\n" ;
    }
}
//printing final output.
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```js
var size = 8;
var block = '#';
var space = ' ';

for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
  var line = '';

  for (var y = 1; y <= size; y++) {
    if (i % 2) {
      if (y % 2) {
        line = line + space;
      } else {
        line = line + block;
      }
    } else {
      if (y % 2) {
        line = line + block;
      } else {
        line = line + space;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var x = "";
var y = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  x = "#" + " " + "#" + " " + "#" + " " + "#";
  y = " " + "#" + " " + "#" + " " + "#" + " " + "#";
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution ...

```js
var board = "";

//you can also set the size of the grid
var size = 8;

for (var i = 1; i < size; i++) {

  for (var j = 1; j < size; j++) {

    if (i % 2 === 0) {

      board += "#";
      board += " ";

    } else {

      board += " ";
      board += "#";

    };

  };

  board += "\n";
};

console.log(board);
```

Comment: Your board has 16 squares per side. Each # and space is a square.

Comment: I'm flagging this as not providing a real answer, because "_Here is my solution ..._" does not explain your code snippet (which itself has far too much whitespace in it, I think)

Comment: hi @Clijsters. Though I agree with you that this could do with an explanation. It is an attempt to answer the question and as such shouldn't be flagged. I'd suggest the appropriate thing to do here is downvote and request that the answerer explain his solution.

Comment: As I remember there is a nice meta post explaining why posts just containing code aren't answers. Can't refer now

Answer (score -1):

Above solution is good using for loop.Lets have fun with while loop.

```js
var board = "";
var even = " # # # #";
var odd = "# # # #";
var i = 1;
while (i <= 8) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(even);
  } else {
    console.log(odd);
  }
  var i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let size = 8;

let board = "";

for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {

  for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {

    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
      board += " ";
    } else {
      board += "#";
    }
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to explain why this answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    console.log("#" + "\t" + "#" + "\t" + "#" + "\t" + "#" + "\t");
  } else console.log("\t" + "#" + "\t" + "#" + "\t" + "#" + "\t" + "#" + "\t");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

---

```js
let chess = "";
for(let i = 0; i< 8; i += 1){
    for(let j=0; j < 8; j += 1){
        if((i+j) % 2 == 0){
            chess += "#";
        }
        else{
            chess += " ";
        }
    }
    chess += "\n";
}
console.log(chess);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

How about this implementation simple and straight-forward

```js
function chessBoard(size) {
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      console.log('' + '# # # #');
    } else {
      console.log(' ' + '# # # #');
    }
  }
}

chessBoard(8);
```

Answer (score -3):

It's pretty simple... 2 loops... the first loop counts the numbers of columns and the second one repeats "#" 4 times per column, inside it. The distance with "# " is the distance between the character "#" each other. While the number of the column is odd the distance will be before "#" . The variable "chr" is to save these repeats inside it to each column.

```js
var chr = '';
for (var num = 0; num < 8; num++) {
  for (var num_1 = 0; num_1 <= 3; num_1++) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) chr += "#  ";
    else chr += "  #";
  }
  console.log(chr)
  chr = '';
}
```